# convert bitmap to image c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert bitmap to image c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606784/convert-bitmap-to-image-c)

I want to convert a bitmap to an image object and display it .
This is my code:

```
//using System.Drawing;

Image objImage = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("large.jpg"));//From File
int height = objImage.Height;//Actual image width
int width = objImage.Width;//Actual image height

Bitmap bitmapimage = new Bitmap(objImage, width, height);// create bitmap with same size of Actual image
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapimage);              

Image bitmap2 = (Image)Bitmap.FromFile(Server.MapPath("logo.png"));
g.DrawImage(bitmap2, (objImage.Width-bitmap2.Width) / 2,( objImage.Height-bitmap2.Height )/ 2);
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
bitmapimage.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

How can I convert the bitmap image into an image object?
Thank you,
Alina