# convert bitmap to image for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is how my code look now:

```
System.Drawing.Image objImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("aaa.jpg"));

int height = objImage.Height;
int width = objImage.Width;

System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapimage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(objImage, width, height);
System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmapimage);
System.Drawing.Image bitmap2 = (System.Drawing.Image)Bitmap.FromFile(Server.MapPath("sem.png"));

g.DrawImage(bitmap2, (objImage.Width - bitmap2.Width) / 2, (objImage.Height - bitmap2.Height) / 2);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();     
bitmapimage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

String saveImagePath = Server.MapPath("ImagesMerge/") + "aaa.jpg";
bitmapimage.Save(saveImagePath);
imgBig.ImageUrl = saveImagePath;
```

The problem I have now is  that the image is not displayed in browser, I don't understand why .

Comment: You question is unclear. Can you describe you task in more details?

Comment: I want to merge a .jpg with a .png. The result I want to be dsplayed in an image control from my page.

Comment: The merged image I want to be displayed in an <image tag

Comment: In the image-control, you'll point to the image file OR image handler. So what you need to know is "how to dynamically create an image with an asp.net handler or .ashx file". See http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=dynamic+image+asp.net&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8 for some helpful articles...

Comment: Are you able to see the image on your file system? How are you trying to display the image on the browser?

Answer (score 3):

like **jmaglasang** said, I would suggest to you to use an ashx file and if you don't need to keep the image, just send the image stream directly to the http without saving it on the disk

so you only need to do something like

```
       <img src="Handler.ashx?action=merge&image1=blah.jpg&image2=bloh.jpg">
```

look at [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaNET_2.aspx) for an example of how to send an image made in memory that does not exist on the drive

Answer (score 2):

`Bitmap` is a subclass of `Image`, so there no need to convert `Bitmap` to `Image`. It already is...

Answer (score 2):

Probably because `saveImagePath` will be a local path (such as `c:\somepath\aaa.jpg`) that is not reachable from the browser. You probably want to set the `ImageUrl = "ImagesMerge/aaa.jpg"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
imgBig.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl(saveImagePath);
```

**EDIT:**

If saveImagePath is under the WebApplication Directory, doing some modifications on the directory structure i.e. modifying files, deleting and creating can cause the application pool to recycle, and once it reaches the maximum recycle count the application pool will be stopped causing "Server unavailable" error.

I would suggests to add/save/modify images on a separate directory (not under the Apps Directory) then create a Handler(ASHX) that will read the images, just an advice though.

Answer (score 0):

MapPath will give you a **physycal** address, not a virtual address which is what the browser needs to get to the image.

Answer (score 0):

You might be forgetting to set the Response.Headers. Check out the following example that shows how to create bar chart images and then display it on the screen:

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/399_Creating_Bar_Chart_Using__NET_Graphics_API.aspx